# GameObject rotate back and forth

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

i'm working on some grass for my game where it needs to look like there is wind. So i tried to write a script, but no succes at all. The script will be something like where it rotates a bit, and then the other way. Just back and forth.

```
public GameObject grass;

    private void FixedUpdate()
    {
        grass.transform.Rotate(transform.rotation.x, transform.rotation.y, 90f * Time.deltaTime, Space.Self);
    }
```

As you can see at my code, it will rotate around itself for eternity. That's just what i got.

Answer (score 1):

First of all you wouldn't want to do this in `FixedUpdate` but rather in `Update` otherwise you get a jittery movement.

Then you could simply define your two target rotations and use [`Mathf.PingPong`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Mathf.PingPong.html) as factor in [`Quaternion.Slerp`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Quaternion.Slerp.html) in order to interpolate forth and back between two rotations:

```
public Vector3 eulerAngles1;
public Vector3 eulerAngles2;
// How long it takes to go from eulerAngles1 to eulerAngles2
public float duration;

Quaternion rotation1;
Quaternion rotation2;

private void Start()
{
    rotation1 = Quaternion.Euler(eulerAngles1);
    rotation2 = Quaternion.Euler(eulerAngles2);
}

private void Update()
{
    var factor = Marhf.PingPong(Time.time / duration, 1);
    // Optionally you can even add some ease-in and -out
    factor = Mathf.SmoothStep(0, 1, factor);

    // Now interpolate between the two rotations on the current factor
    transform.rotation = Qiaternion.Slerp(rotation1, rotation2, factor);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've never done something with Unity, but you might try something like this.

If you want a nice *wave* effect, you should use a `Math.Sin()` for that. Maybe something like:

```
public GameObject grass;
private double _time;

    private void FixedUpdate()
    {
        _time = _time + Time.deltaTime;

        // I assumed that the angle for unity is in degrees.
        // Math.Sin work with Radians. a full wave will take about 6 seconds.
        // It will go between 0 and 90 degrees.
        var angle = (float)(45 + (45 * Math.Sin(_time))); 

        grass.transform.Rotate(transform.rotation.x, transform.rotation.y, angle, Space.Self);
    }
```

If you want the rotation got from -45 to 45 degrees, use: `(float)(45 * Math.Sin(_time));`